# PHP / SQL Prevent Update

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently using this snippet below, it currently updates the database with the activatin code but I want it to just check if the activatino code has been used if so show error message if error message hasn't been used direct the user to the next form.

```
$sql = "SELECT `Check_Activation` 
        FROM `members` WHERE (`Check_Activation` = $activation_code )
        AND (`Activation` = )";

if ($sql->affected_rows > 0)
{
    $username = substr($username, 0, 1);
    if($username == 1) { 
        header( 'Location: form-one.php?membernumber='
                .$usernameurl.'&activation_code='
                .$activation_codeurl.'' ) ;
    } elseif($username == 2) { 
        header( 'Location: form-two.php?membernumber='
                .$usernameurl.'&activation_code='
                .$activation_codeurl.'' ) ;                 
    } elseif($username == 3) { 
        header( 'Location: form-three.php?membernumber='
                .$usernameurl.'&activation_code='
                .$activation_codeurl.'' ) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with applying logic to your MySQL database table structure.

For example;

```
CREATE TABLE used_codes (uid SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL, code VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uid   | smallint(5) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| code  | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set
```

Now, when a code is used, insert it into this table;

```
INSERT INTO used_codes (uid, code) VALUES (?,?)
```

When someone tries to use a code, simply query this MySQL database table `WHERE code = ?` and if a row is returned, the code has already been used.

**Alternatively, you could use a flag in `Members` which sets a value of a column called `code_used` to 1 (0 would be default - not used)**

### Or use what you already have

*and query what we have already stored*

```
SELECT `column` FROM `Members` WHERE (`User_Activated` = 1) AND (`Activation` = ?)
```

I think your version of `User_Activated` is `Check_Activation`, but I'm not sure.
If that query returns a row, we know that this activation code has already been used.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi are you using a random activation code or letting the user create the activation code?

you might be better of using AJAX to check if the username has been used before and letting the user know so they can change the username.

Comment: Who mentioned anything about checking the username?

Comment: I was just looking at your code and you are collecting a username so I'm assuming they are creating a username to enter into the table or users? my apologises if I have misread the code

Comment: "but I want it to just check if the activation code has been used" (It's not my code, by the way ;))

Comment: how are you getting the activation code? to check against the activation code in your table